# Show that $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is a normed space.

Tags: normed-spaces

> Show that $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_1)$ is a normed space.

Any help would be appreciated, I don't fully understand the notation. Is this the Euclidean norm?

Comment: If $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)^T$ then $||x||_p=(|x_1|^p+\dots+|x_n|^p)^{\frac{1}{p}}$. So $p=2$ is the Euclidean norm, and $||x||_1=|x_1|+\dots+|x_n|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(R^n, ||\:.||_1)$ denotes the $n$ dimensional space of real numbers endowed with the $||\:.||_1$ norm. The question is really asking if this particular norm norm makes sense when applied to this vector space.

This norm is commonly referred to as the $L_1$ norm, or the Manhattan distance. Like Carmichael561 said in the comments, the $L_2$ norm is the Euclid distance. In order to show that $||.||_1$ is a norm, we have to show that it has the three properties all norms have:

Positive Definiteness: for any $x \in R^n, ||x||_1 \geq 0,$ and only equal to $0$ if $x = 0$. 
Here 0 is the 0 vector in $R^n.$

Scalar Multiplication: for $\alpha \in R,$ $||\alpha x|| = |\alpha| \: ||x|| $.

The Triangle Inequality: for any $x,y \in R^n, ||x + y|| \leq ||x|| + ||y||.$

Prove these three things to show that $||\:.||_1$ is a norm for $R^n.$